# Unable to apply patch SUPEE-8788 to Magento Community version 1.5.1.0

Tags: supee-8788v2

I have been unable to apply this patch for a while and am unable to find any resources about it due to the Magento version being so old.

Has anyone had any success applying this patch?  I know that it relied on patch SUPEE-3941 which was never released for versions below 1.8 I believe?

This is my error when trying to apply.

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

```
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Email/Template/Preview.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 76.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Compare.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Cart.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ProductAlert/Block/Email/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Mysql4/Order/Payment.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Mysql4/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Mysql4/Quote/Payment.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Mysql4/Recurring/Profile.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Controller/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/productalert/price.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/productalert/stock.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/form.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/reorder/sidebar.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tag/customer/view.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/checkout/cart.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/customer/form/login.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/wishlist/view.phtml
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
checking file downloader/Maged/View.php
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 372.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
checking file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
```

Comment: do you get an error message? What is happening exactly?

Comment: Error message.  Sorry it's so long, the issue has been updated with my error message

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to have **/downloader/** available on your production environment so you don't need to install SUPEE-3941, this security patch is all about **downloader**.

Just install SUPEE-8788 v2 for Magento CE 1.5.1.0, download it from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download (archive tab, ctrl (cmd) + f : SUPEE-8788)

Comment: I have tried to do that before, however still getting error messages, I have updated my post with the message.